# proving $f^{-1}(C\cup D)=f^{-1}(C)\cup f^{-1}(D)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, proof-verification

I don't understand why I have to prove these:

$f^{-1}(C\cup D)\subseteq f^{-1}(C)\cup f^{-1}(D)$

$f^{-1}(C)\cup f^{-1}(D)\subseteq f^{-1}(C\cup D) $

Why can't I do something like that:
$x\in f^{-1}(C\cup D)\Leftrightarrow  f(x) \in C \cup D \Leftrightarrow f(x) \in C \vee f(x) \in D \Leftrightarrow x\in f^{-1}(C) \vee x \in f^{-1}(D) \\ \Leftrightarrow x\in f^{-1}(C) \cup f^{-1}(D)$

Can I prove $f^{-1}(C\cap D)=f^{-1}(C)\cap f^{-1}(D)$ in the same way?

Thanks.

Comment: Of course you can. And that is just your initial thesis, reworded.

Comment: I think you have the $\wedge$ and $\vee$ symbols backwards; otherwise I agree.

Comment: I just noticed the question asked "why I have to prove" and not "how to prove." The point is that some things which seem obvious aren't true, for instance, think about the relationship between $f^{-1}(f(C))$ and $C$. This, on the other hand, is something that seems obvious and in fact is obvious, but it still helps to write down a quick argument to make sure you're not deceiving yourself.

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake. I'm fixing this right now.

Comment: I agree with @hunter. $f\left(A\cap B\right)=f\left(A\right)\cap f\left(B\right)$ is an example. It seems obvious but doesn't have to be true. If $\wedge$ is changed into $\vee$ then your proof is correct and
you can do the same for the intersection (with $\cap$ and $\wedge$).

Comment: Everything is fine now.

Comment: $x\in f^{-1}(C\cap D)\Leftrightarrow  f(x) \in C \cap D \Leftrightarrow f(x) \in C \wedge f(x) \in D \Leftrightarrow x\in f^{-1}(C) \wedge x \in f^{-1}(D) \\ \Leftrightarrow x\in f^{-1}(C) \cap f^{-1}(D)$ 
Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, it is even perfect.